# OpenID Connect Persist ID Token to Server-side Callback Function

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid, access-token

Suppose that I invoke the following HTTP request:

```
https://accounts.example.com/oauth2/auth?
scope=openid+email&
nonce=53f2495d7b435ac571&
redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foauth2demo.appspot.com%2Foauthcallback&
response_type=id_token+token&
client_id=753560681145-2ik2j3snsvbs80ijdi8.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

Which yields the following redirect response:

```
https://oauth2demo.appspot.com/oauthcallback#
access_token=ya29.AHES6ZSzX
token_type=Bearer&
expires_in=3600&
id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhY2NvdW50cy5nb29nbGUuY29tIiwiY...
```

What is the point of the callback parameter, given that the returned metadata, containing id_token, etc., is positioned after a hash fragment in the URI, and are therefore not persisted as parameters to the callback function? How can a server-side callback receive the various tokens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response type that is used here is a so-called "Implicit" response type which is primarily meant for in-browser (e.g. Javascript) clients, in which case the Javascript code that is served on the callback URL can access the parameters in the fragment. Web applications should do either one of:

1. stick to the `code` flow which is meant for web application clients
2. use the Form Post response mode (http://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-form-post-response-mode-1_0.html) if supported by the OP
3. serve Javascript on the callback URL that parses out the parameters from the fragment and POSTs them to the server

Bottom line is that if you need the tokens server-side, you should most probably use the `code` response type.

Comment: Thanks. From here, I presume the next step in determining a user's claims is to request an access-token, and use that to invoke the user-info endpoint?

Comment: If the claims present in the id_token are not sufficient for your goal, then yes

Comment: The Authorization Code grant flow doesn't return an ID Token, nor can I configure it do so. Setting the id_token, or id_token token response_type parameters seems to invoke Implicit Grant Flow. The ID Token will not persist to the server. I presume that my only option is to invoke the user-info endpoint.

Comment: if you provide the scope `openid` and the OP claims it is an OpenID Connect provider but does not return an `id_token` in the `code` flow, then your OP is broken

Comment: You must include the offline_access scope when requesting the auth code, in order to return the ID Token.

Comment: no, the `offline_access` scope is required to get a `refresh_token`